# Why clone of a draggable element is reverting when dropped in a droppable div in Jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to make image draggable on the given div. I want to use clone of small image to be dragged and drop into the div. My code is

**HTML**

```
    <div class="option" id="f">
    <img class="options" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-h-g-49-66-3.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="lame">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""/>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
              $(function() {
    $( ".options" ).draggable({ cursor: "pointer",opacity: 0.6,helper: "clone"
        });
    $(".lame").droppable({ accept:".options"
    });
});
```

This code work fine if I don't use the helper:"clone". What can be the right method to do this drag n drop process proper using new jQuery and jQuery ui version. the [Jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/dkNs7/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your `.lame.droppable(` code  to the following.

```
$(".lame").droppable({ accept:".options",drop: function(event, ui) {
    $.ui.ddmanager.current.cancelHelperRemoval = true;}
});
```

Comment: hey can i make my dropped cloned image resizable and draggable with in the droppable div ??

Comment: I'll see what I can do, I'll have some time to look into it later today.